# replace www.anylinks.com or anylinks.com to http://www.anylinks.com within the html content

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need help with replacing the links to the format 'http://www.link.com'

ex: from

```
    $output_string = 'fix me <a href="www.link.com">link</a> or fix me <a href="link.com">link</a> and fix me too <a href="http://link.com">link</a> and replace me with <a href="http://www.link.com>link</a>';
```

to

```
    $output_string = 'fix me <a href="http://www.link.com">link</a> or fix me <a href="http://www.link.com">link</a> and fix me too <a href="http://www.link.com">link</a> and replace me with <a href="http://www.link.com>link</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You may not want to rewrite `http://anylinks.com` to `http://www.anylinks.com` as some domains don't work with the `www` prefix.

Comment: i happened to come across a website, where its www version was a completely other site. i just want to say that www.example.com != example.com and of course the same applies for the protocol.

Comment: That's what I was getting at @Sharky, also some sites won't have `www` active because they'll instantly direct to SSL which may only be valid without the subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`str_replace`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function to achieve this

```
$str = 'fix me <a href="www.link.com">link</a> or fix me <a href="link.com">link</a> and fix me too <a href="http://link.com">link</a> and replace me with <a href="http://www.link.com>link</a>';
echo str_replace('www.www', 'www', str_replace('http://www.http://', 'http://www.', str_replace('a href="', 'a href="http://www.', $str)));
```

This will output

```
'fix me <a href="http://www.link.com">link</a> or fix me <a href="http://www.link.com">link</a> and fix me too <a href="http://www.link.com">link</a> and replace me with <a href="http://www.link.com>link</a>'
```

###[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/WDU4Sb)

Comment: I think a better approach is the case-insensitive version of this function - [str_ireplace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php).

Comment: i think the better approach will be a regex, anyhow you need to change the replace of www.www => www to www.www. => www. because it will fail if the website starts with h t t p : / /www and www is part of the name (example here http://3v4l.org/hHKeK) h t t p : / / wwwoooohoooo.com

Answer (score 0):

```
$output_string = preg_replace('/(href=\")(http:\/\/)?/i', '$1http://', $output_string);
```

This regexp will find href tags in string and adds http:// if its not already there. Better then searching for 'www' since the URL might not start with www. It's not case-sensitive.